# SwiftUI View .tint(_ Color) method doesn't work

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios15, tintcolor, accent-color

I'm trying to change tint color for View.

What I got:

```
    var body: some View {
    Button {
        selectedTab = title
    } label: {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            image.renderingMode(.template)
            Text(title)
        }
        .foregroundColor(selectedTab == title ? .accentColor : .black.opacity(0.2))
        .padding()
    }
}
```

The problem:
When I use .accentColor(Color) in superview for this subview, Xcode said:
[image]

So, I use, like in docs: [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/tint(_:)) ***Use this method to override the default accent color for this view.***  :

```
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            CustomTabView(tabs: "").tint(.red)
        } else {
            CustomTabView(tabs: "").accentColor(.green)
        }
```

Accent color work fine, but .tint doesn't. What I do wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes, I find that `foregroundColor` works when `tint` doesn't. If that works, you might even be able to get rid of the `#available` check, since `foregroundColor` is available on iOS 14.

Comment: Hi @Bbrk24. It is my pet-project, I have got min 14 iOS. ) btw I've checked foreground color too, and it doesn't worked...

Comment: If you want to use the same accent color everywhere, you can change the Accent Color in your app's asset catalogue. If not, then I don't have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because when you use `tint`, and you select the tab, the tab's color gets overridden by the `foregroundColor` modifier. It'd set the tab's color to `.accentColor`, which is independent from the color that `tint` sets. The deprecated `accentColor` however, does set it, so that's why the deprecated `accentColor` modifier works.

One way to work around this is simply not use `.accentColor` for the foreground color. Use `nil` instead:

```
.foregroundColor(selectedTab == title ? nil : .black.opacity(0.2))
```

When it is nil, it will not override the tint.

Comment: Thank u! that's work! But why they write  "Use this method to override the default accent color for this view" ? .accentColor != tint accentColor's ? Too many "accent colors" to understanding... )

Comment: @SergeyUdalov After the `accentColor` modifier is deprecated, you can think of the `accentColor` *property* as get-only. The system decides what the most appropriate tint color is, depending on the user's settings and preferences. On the other hand, the `tint` modifier allows you to set your own tint color. This is not the user's preference (it is *your* preference!), so it is not the same as `accentColor`.